# Android - Trying to give links to open web in two button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new android development, i tried to give links to open webpage for two buttons and i get the error "} expected at line xx" can some one just check any whether i got problem with my java? and fix the closing tag issue too.

```js
package com.domain.app;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

 public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

     Button button;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         addListenerOnButton();

     }

     public void addListenerOnButton() {

         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Red);

         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
                 startActivity(browserIntent);
             }

         });

         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Blue);

         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                 startActivity(browserIntent);
             }

         });

     }
 }
```

Comment: You're forgetting a } before the line "public class MyAndroidAppActivity..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;        

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
//Try putting one here } OR (see bottom)
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

 Button button;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     addListenerOnButton();

 }

 public void addListenerOnButton() {

     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Red);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));
             startActivity(browserIntent);
         }

     });

     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Blue);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
             startActivity(browserIntent);
         }

     });

 }
}

//Or here }
```

Comment: could you give me an example code please, because when tried to insert the "}" this before the Public class MyAndroidAppActivity I get it as a big error.

Comment: Check the commented lines. Try each of those.

Comment: That worked well but app force closes on the click of button! Any idea? Is there any wrong with Java?

Comment: I would ask another question. Can you please mark this as correct?

Comment: Got it worked! I used Intent to link the button to web :) thnaks mahn :)